# Dynamic_cast fails, even though I am(as far as I can tell) definitely casting from a properly-derived class.

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

So basically I have a class:

```
class Rigidbody
{
    Collider _collider;
    //blah
}
```

The `Collider` class looks like

```
class Collider
{
    public:
        Collider(Transform trans);
        virtual ~Collider();

        void SetType(const ColliderType newType){_type = newType;}
        const ColliderType GetType(){return _type;}

        void SetTransform(const Transform& trans) { _transform = trans; }
        const Transform& GetTransform() { return _transform; }

    private:
        ColliderType _type;
        Transform _transform;
};
```

There are a couple of derived classes; for instance:

```
class CircleCollider : public Collider
{
    public:
        CircleCollider(Transform trans);
        ~CircleCollider();

        const float GetRadius(){return _radius;}
        void SetRadius(const float newRad) { _radius = newRad; }

    private:
        float _radius;
};
```

In my physics class, basically I have to call the correct collision method, based on which derived classes are colliding (the code for Box vs Circle is different to Circle vs Circle).  So I use stuff like

```
if(CircleCollider* circ1 = dynamic_cast<CircleCollider*>(&bodyA.GetCollider()))
{
    CircleVsCircle(circ1, circ2)
}
```

etc.

To test this, I create a Rigidbody, then do

```
CircleCollider coll(player->GetTransform());
coll.SetRadius(10.0f);
player->SetCollider(coll);
```

So the player's collider should be an instance of CircleCollider.  But when I try to dynamic cast it to CircleCollider, the cast fails.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just guessing here (since you don't show the `GetCollider` function), but the `GetCollider` function returns `Rigidbody::_collider` then you don't actually *have* a `CircleCollider` object, all you have is a `Collider` object.

For the polymorphism to work the `Rigidbody::_collider` needs to be a pointer, and actually initialized to a pointer to a `CircleCollider` object.

Related reading: [*object slicing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) (it's what happens if you assign a `CircleCollider` object to the `_collider` object).

Comment: Thank you very much, Joachim!  And thanks for the extra reading, I'll look at that before I get back to coding!

Answer (score 3):

```
class Rigidbody
{
    Collider _collider;

}; // < This had fallen off
```

In your `RigidBody` class, you store an instance of `Collider`. Not something derived from a `Collider`, but a `Collider`.

Polymorphism implies indirection : if you wish to store someting derived from `Collider`, you need to use a pointer or a reference. In your example, that would be a `Collider*` (you can reset it, and the `RigidBody` doesn't own it).

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!  So basically, when I did `SetCollider`, the compiler upcast the CircleCollider to a Collider (or something along those lines)?  EDIT: Going to give Joachim the "answer", because he replied first.

Comment: @Makcheese Exactly. The `Collider` part of the `CircleCollider` has been "extracted" to assign to the other `Collider`, and the derived part has been *sliced* off (see Joachim's answer). Regarding your project as a whole, another concept that may help you is the Visitor pattern, which would replace those `dynamic_cast`s in an extensible way.

Comment: Thanks again!  With regard to the Visitor pattern, I'll definitey look into it!

Comment: _"Polymorphism implies indirection"_ Mmm not really but I understand why you think so.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You piked my curiosity. Are there instances of polymorphism that avoid indirection altogether ? I gather from you not outright refuting that it must be something far-fetched :p

Comment: Well, for a start, technically references do not involve indirection (although we all know they're generally implemented in that way). Furthermore, yeah, like calling a `virtual` member function from a member function in the base class - doesn't matter what handles to the object you have. Indirection or not, you will see the effects of polymorphism. It's just that there are close to no other ways to do so except by naming the callee in an expression, and it's close to impossible to do that without slicing unless you've employed pointers or references. So it's a nitpick but an accurate one ;)

Comment: inb4 but the member function call uses `this` AH-HA YOU SAY

Comment: I have been nitpicked to death, but wasn't expecting less.